# Oracle SQL - insert into select statement - error

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-insert

I created an insert statement, inside that insert statement I would like to pull data from another column in another table. I wrote the following script and get an error.

I wrote the actual select statement and it worked by itself, here is the script:

```
SELECT job_id 
FROM JOBS 
WHERE job_id IN ('AD_CMMS')
```

The problem occurs when I try to incorporate the insert into statement with the select statement, below is the complete script including the select statement:

```
INSERT INTO Employees
VALUES (242, 'Anouar', 'seljouki', 'seljouki84@gmail.com', '0662777081', date19-May-12,
        SELECT job_id FROM JOBS WHERE job_id IN ('AD_CMMS'), 
        16000, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

When I run the script above, I get this error:

> Error starting at line : 26 in command -
> INSERT INTO Employees
> VALUES (242,'Anouar','seljouki','seljouki84@gmail.com','0662777081',date19-May-12,
> SELECT job_id from JOBS where job_id in('AD_CMMS'),16000,NULL,NULL,Null)
> Error at Command Line : 28 Column : 1
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Comment: Why are you even bothering to reference the second table?  The only column you are pulling from it is JOB_ID, and you are filtering that table on JOB_ID.  So you already know the value you want to insert without even selecting from the second table.  The only real question is what do you want to do if that one value of JOB_ID does not exist in the JOBS table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scalar subquery needs to be surrounded with parentheses. Also, the date literal syntax needs to be fixed.

So:

```
INSERT into Employees 
VALUES (
    242,
    'Anouar',
    'seljouki',
    'seljouki84@gmail.com',
    '0662777081',
    date '2012-05-19', 
    (SELECT job_id from JOBS where job_id = 'AD_CMMS'),
    16000,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

Beware that the subquery *must not* return more than one row, otherwise you would get an error.

You could also phrase this as an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement; this guarantees that the row will not be inserted if there is no match in `JOBS`:

```
INSERT into Employees 
SELECT 
    242,
    'Anouar',
    'seljouki',
    'seljouki84@gmail.com',
    '0662777081',
    date '2012-05-19', 
    job_id,
    16000,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
FROM JOBS 
WHERE job_id = 'AD_CMMS'
```

Side notes:

- if you need to stick the the current date format that is showed in your question, then use `to_date('19-May-12', 'dd-mon-yy')` instead.
- it is a good practice to enumerate the target columns for insert

Comment: I got a message saying: 1 Raw was inserted. The problem is I go the Employees table , I try to filter under to filter under data tab with the data I added and I Find nothing. I tried clicking refresh and even closed Oracle SQL developer and open it and the same thing

Comment: @AnouarSeljouki: you might need to `commit` first.

Comment: what is Commit? forgive me I am new to Oracle SQL

Comment: @AnouarSeljouki: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html